# How can I get vite to gracefully skip/ignore this dependency that is not used, but blocking my app from running?

Tags: vite, sveltekit, skeleton-ui

**How can I get vite to gracefully skip/ignore this dependency that is not used, but blocking my app from running?**

There is a vite error while updating dependencies in a 3rd party library (SkeletonUI), which causes my SvelteKit app to stop functioning.

I don't think this specific dependency (a Skeleton "Modal" Svelte component) is used at all in my project.

Eventually the root cause of the error will be fixed by Svelte and/or Skeleton devs, but until then it's blocking progress on my own SvelteKit app.

The error:

```
[vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/.pnpm/@skeletonlabs+skeleton@2.7.0_svelte@5.0.0-next.32/node_modules/@skeletonlabs/skeleton/dist/utilities/Modal/Modal.svelte:9:47: ERROR: "modalStore" cannot be bound multiple times in the same parameter list
```

---

I tried telling vite it was external like this, but it didn't work:

```
    // vite.config.js
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: /.*Modal.*/,
        },
    },
```